# Bootstrap Vertical Align Small Column Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap page that is basically two columns. One column has several columns and content in it which makes it very large and the other has just an image. I am trying to get that image vertically centered to the left column. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 features">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      This column has a lot of content and gets to be about 700px
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 small-column-align">
    <img src="inc/img/robot-warrior.jpg" width="717" height="837" alt="" style="max-width:80%; height:auto;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS for small-column-align is

```
.small-column-align{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

For some reason the right column is always top aligned though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the column width to col-sm-6 on both div's, and that makes the two divs float one below each other, try to put it col-sm-5 on both and also put the class "small-column-align" to both div's.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5 small-column-align">
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <img src="http://labs.sogeti.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/google-car.jpg" width="717" height="837" alt="" style="max-width:80%; height:auto;"/>


    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 small-column-align">


    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <img src="http://labs.sogeti.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/google-car.jpg" width="717" height="837" alt="" style="max-width:80%; height:auto;"/>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
    <p>This is a text content for sm 5</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.small-column-align {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12674/

Hope it works, let me know your thoughts,

Leo.

Comment: So I'm confused as to why this works. I understand why you set the left column to inline-block if you're going to set the float to none, buy bootstrap is a 12 block grid why would you need to set it to a 10 block grid to get it to work?

Comment: I don't know why but setting the with of the columns (col-xx-6) to 49.7% put the divs in the right position, col-xx-5 is about 42% so thats why it works that way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```css
.features-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.features-wrap > div {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.features {
  flex: 1;
}

.small-column-align {
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row features-wrap">
  <div class="col-sm-6 features">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      This column has a lot of content and gets to be about 700px
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 small-column-align">
    <img src="inc/img/robot-warrior.jpg" width="717" height="837" alt="" style="max-width:80%; height:auto;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This way does work. Can you explain why it works for others reading this?

Comment: That's the power of flexbox display. Just read this post from CSS Tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/